Movie using Sepia tones for flashback that caused confusion
I'm looking for a film that I think is from 2000-2010. It's a film I never watched so I don't know a lot of plot details, but I think it either a Jane Austen or Little Women type thing (I know there's quite a bit of difference there).
The important point that I remember is that the film mixed two time periods of the main character. Childhood and adult storylines were interwoven throughout the film, with the childhood periods tinted differently, I think using Sepia tones and this was considered confusing by audiences. Some people never understood that the brown tinted scenes were happening many years in the past.
It is the confusion/backlash I recall from when the movie was released rather than the movie itself.
I've been through Decade Themed Filter and Monochrome Past without finding anything that jumps out.

Are you sure it was a movie? The TV series "Any Day Now" (1998) featured a related past and present story line (in every episode) and, although it's been years since I've seen it, I recall the flashback scenes using a different colorization than the present day ones. I do not, however, recall back lash over this technique.

@Tronman I'm almost 100% certain it was a movie.  If only because I can't recall a TV show ever getting this kind of backlash at a level that penetrates through to a mainstream level.

Okie dokie. I ran through the list here but nothing seemed to fit the time period and the backlash.
https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonochromePast
